# Empty transforms using Robot State Publisher

Tags: ros, urdf, robot-state-publisher, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to broadcast moving joint states using my robot state publisher. I echoed the topic on which I broadcast my state, all I get is :

```
transforms: []
---
```

Here's my code section responsible for broadcasting the state :

```
auto transforms = std::map<std::string, double>();
        while (publish) {
            transforms.insert(std::make_pair("base_link", controller->getJointCurrentAngle(
                    Controller::JOINT_ID(Controller::JOINT::BASE_JOINT_ID))));
            transforms.insert(std::make_pair("joint_1", controller->getJointCurrentAngle(
                    Controller::JOINT_ID(Controller::JOINT::SHOULDER_JOINT_ID))));
            transforms.insert(std::make_pair("joint_2", controller->getJointCurrentAngle(
                    Controller::JOINT_ID(Controller::JOINT::ELBOW_JOINT_ID))));
            transforms.insert(std::make_pair("joint_3", controller->getJointCurrentAngle(
                    Controller::JOINT_ID(Controller::JOINT::WRIST_JOINT_ID))));
            publisher.get()->publishTransforms(transforms,ros::Time::now(),"");
            transforms.clear();
            usleep(1000);
        }
```

When I use publishFixedTransform("") instead of publishTransforms, I get my transforms correctly published to the topic, but I cannot move them since I use a KDL tree from an URDF file to create my robot model.

Do you guys have any tip of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217567/empty-transforms-using-robot-state-publisher/) by [kritchie](https://answers.ros.org/users/5411/kritchie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-09-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solenoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27793/solenoid/) on 2016-08-19**:
Did you find an answer to your issue, I am in the same situation and cannot figure this out... Joints are published, but transforms are empty, subscriptions are all correct: robot->joints->robot_state_publisher->tf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Out of curiosity (and not an answer): any particular reason that you are trying to directly publish TF frames in this way? Typical setups publish `JointState` msgs, and the `robot_state_publisher` then does all the hard work. That would seem to make things much easier (but adds a node).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0